# How to extract a number from string using a javascript or jQuery without regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Take three text fields.

1) field 1 - allow any  special character to start and end with alphabets  but allow numbers, coma and decimal in the middle ex: 
$123456.00X

2) same as in field 1

3) same as in field 1

4) display each number when you type in field 1 below the field as display mode

5) calculate button should calculate as field 1 value multiply with field 2

value and the decide by field 3 value. while calculating handle non numeric values and remove non numbers as displayed and show the result.

```
   div id="divMyTestPage" class="col-xs-12">
  <h1 class="mt5 mb10 main-title card"><i class="fa fa-caret-down mr5"> 
  </i>Client Side Page:<span class="ml10"><span class="text-bold ml10"> 
  </span><span id="spnMessage" class="pull-right" style="color: green"> 
  </span></span><span class="pull-right ml5 mt-1 wf-status"></span></h1>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="firstNumber" placeholder="Enter Here" 
  class="mb5" onchange="inputFunction()" /><br>
        <span id="firstDemo"></span><br />
        <input type="text" id="secondNumber" placeholder="Enter Here" 
   class="mb5" onchange="inputFunction()" /><br>
        <span id="secondDemo"></span><br />
        <input type="text" id="thirdNumber" placeholder="Enter Here" 
  class="mb5" onchange="inputFunction()" /><br>
        <span id="thirdDemo"></span><br />
        <br />
        <input type="button" onclick="multiplyNumbers()" class="mb10" 
  Value="Calculate" />
        <div>
            The Calculation is : <br>
            <span id="calculate"></span>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function inputFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    var fn = parseFloat(x);
    document.getElementById("firstDemo").innerHTML = fn;
    var y = document.getElementById("secondNumber").value;
    var sn = parseFloat(y);
    document.getElementById("secondDemo").innerHTML = sn;
    var z = document.getElementById("thirdNumber").value;
    var tn = parseFloat(z);
    document.getElementById("thirdDemo").innerHTML = tn;

 };
function multiplyNumbers() {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstDemo").innerHTML;
    num2 = document.getElementById("secondDemo").innerHTML;
    num3 = document.getElementById("thirdDemo").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("calculate").innerHTML = (num1 * num2) / num3;
 };
 </script>
```

This is my code, i have written in simple javascript.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yourself yet? If you have a specific problem you're running into, please ask that.

Comment: Why not use regex?

Comment: Regex is likely the best approach here.  If not, what about running a string replace on Alpha characters with a null?

Comment: Also consider disallowing non-numeric characters in the number fields and putting a span with `$` (or whatever) at the beginning and end of the input instead.

Comment: Can please type  the code for me.

Answer (score 0):

If its the extraction you're worried about, then this is how you can do it.

```
var x = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value; // "$123456.00X"
var y = x.substring(1, x.length - 1); // "123456.00"
var myFloatNum = parseFloat(y); // 123456.00
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
var x = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value; // "$1c2,34.00NM"
var y = x.split(""); // ["$", "1", "c", "2", ",", "3", "4", ".", "0", "0", "N", "M"]
var tempArr= [];
y.forEach((n) => {
  var t = parseInt(n);
  if(!isNaN(t)) { // if t is a number, push it to tempArr
    tempArr.push(t);
  }
});
var myNum = tempArr.join("");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and even i want know to about how to deal with non numeric values.

Comment: field 3 should be non zero and result should also be non numeric and non zero

Comment: For Example: $1c2,34.00NM  how to extract only numbers from this string by using loop statements in the above code.

Comment: see my edit, this can extract number in your given scenario. If this solves your issue, feel free to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: when i am entering  : $1c2,34.00NM, the answer is displaying as 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I should not have done `parseInt` again. Check the updated answer and now it should work perfectly.

Comment: what about the calculation of the numbers?

Comment: you can insert HIDDEN input elements in your HTML and update them when you extract the numeric values. When you click the calculate button, then you can get the values from the hidden input boxes and calculate them.

Comment: please can you help regarding the calculation process

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to extract a a valid number from any alphanumeric string using native javascript.

1. **Convert String in Character Array.**
2. **Check Each Character Array if it is a valid number.**
3. *(Optional) If there are multiple decimals (special characters) in a string then the last decimal wins and all other decimals should be removed.*

You can find working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vibs2006/oaqnkv5a/

```js
    var validNumber = '';
    var inputString = "$1c2,34.00NM";

    function calculateString(inputString) {        
        //Convert String to Character array using Javascript's string split function (actually workaround as Array.From method is not supported in IE 11 and below)
        var charArray = inputString.split("");
        document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'Total Characters in input string are ';
        document.getElementById("divOutput").innerHTML = "";
        validNumber = '';
        
        //Now Looping through each string (character in this case) by using Array object's forEach function
        charArray.forEach(function (char) {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML + "[" + char + "] ";
            
            //Testing if Number is a valid number
            if (!isNaN(char)) {
                validNumber = validNumber.concat(char);
            }

            //Testing for a presence of Decimal. 
            //Please note that for removing multiple validations you need to write more detailed code.
            if (char.indexOf(".") != -1) {
                validNumber = validNumber.concat(char);
            }                 
        });
        
        document.getElementById("divOutput").innerHTML = "String without any special character is '" + validNumber + "'";
    }

    //Executing the function
    calculateString(inputString);       

    //Adding Event Handler for change in text via tab or keypress events
    var inputTxtField = document.getElementById("txtInputOriginalString");
    inputTxtField.addEventListener("change", function (e) {        
        calculateString(inputTxtField.value)
    });

        inputTxtField.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {            
        calculateString(inputTxtField.value)
    });
```

```html
<label>Original String:
        <input type="text" id="txtInputOriginalString" value="$1c2,34.00NM" />
    </label>
    </p>
    <div id="info"></div>
    </p>
    <div id="divOutput"></div>
    </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the **replace** method for extracting number from a string.

```
const str = 'hello 123 world';

const replaced = str.replace(/\D/g, ''); // ️ '123'
```

The first argument we passed to the String.replace method is a regular expression that we want to match in the string.

The `\D` character matches a character that is NOT a digit.

We have added the `g` (global) flag to match all non-digit characters and replace them with an empty string.

And it does solve your issue.